# How to create a syntax rule that can be contained anywhere?

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting

The following snippet from my .vimrc highlights superfluous whitespace at line ends in a shade of gray:

```vim
autocmd Syntax * syntax match MySpace /\s\+$/
autocmd ColorScheme * highlight MySpace ctermbg=238
```

But this does not work when this whitespace is already matched by a syntax group. For example, trailing whitespace in various types of comments is not marked.

The manual talks about the `contains=ALL` option for syntax groups, but there seems to be no analogous `containedin=ALL`. Can I emulate it in any way? The only method I could come up would be to list all relevant syntax groups in the `containedin=` option of `MySpace`, and that's clearly tedious and not at all elegant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know how to do this with `Syntax`, but you can use the [listchars](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Highlight_unwanted_spaces#Using_the_list_and_listchars_options) options to highlight trailing spaces.

From my `.vimrc`:

```
" List chars
set listchars=""           " Reset the listchars
set listchars+=tab:\|\     " show tabs as "|"
set listchars+=nbsp:·      " show non-breaking spaces as "·"
set listchars+=trail:·     " show trailing spaces as "·"
set listchars+=precedes:«
set listchars+=extends:»
```

Comment: Very interesting. I've added `set list listchars=trail:·,nbsp:·,tab:\ \ ` to my `.vimrc`. Fun fact: The two escaped spaces at the end break the syntax highlighting.

Comment: The disadvantage of `'listchars'` is that other characters change their appearance, too. Also, many users will want to highlight trailing-space errors in more aggressive colors.

Comment: You can highlight them via `hi SpecialKey ctermfg=red guifg=red`

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `:match` command (or `matchadd()`), as described in the [Vim Tips Wiki article](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Highlight_unwanted_spaces) about this particular topic.

If you like a ready-to-use solution for this, you can also try out [my ShowTrailingWhitespace plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3966), or one of the alternatives listed on the plugin page.